# prove that $d$ is a metric.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $E=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$, and $d: E\to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $d(x,x)=0$ and $$d(x,y)= 2^{-\min \left\{k\in \mathbb{N}\mid x_k \neq y_k\right\}}$$.
For all $x=(x_k)_k,y=(y_k)_k \in E$, prove that $d$ is a metric.

---

I'm having problems with $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$, Hints are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $k$, 
$$
x_k\neq y_k\quad \Rightarrow\quad  x_k\neq z_k \quad \vee\quad y_k\neq z_k.
$$
Then
$$
\min\{k:x_k\neq y_k\}\geq \min\{k:x_k\neq z_k\} \quad \vee\quad \min\{k:x_k\neq y_k\}\geq \min\{k:y_k\neq z_k\}
 $$
hence 
$$
d(x,y)\leq d(x,z) \quad \vee\quad d(x,y)\leq d(y,z)
$$